# How to create a key:value pair or 2 sets of lists returning item ids and corresponding number of purchases in sql (or snowflake to be more specific)?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bigdata, key-value, clickstream

I have an enormous clickstream data which I can pull the **timestamp**, **user_ids** corresponding **item_ids** that customers clicked.

I am trying to create a dataset that will have the unique customer ids (user_id) on each row and another column that has key:value pair that provides me the list of items and number of times corresponding item is clicked like a python dictionary (or this can be in two columns with items and corresponding num. clicks as a sorted list from most frequent to least). The number of clicks for an item is the times that item_id occur for a fixed user_id. Basically, every occurrence of item is one click. If it occurs 10 times for a fixed user_id, that means that click_count = 10 for that user_id, item_id pair.

Here is an example:

| USER_ID | CLICKED_ITEMS |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | item3: 20, item2: 10, item1: 5 |
| user2 | item1: 10, item2: 1, item3: 1 |
| user3 | item2: 1 |
| user4 | item1: 10, item2: 2 |

or

| USER_ID | CLICKED_ITEMS | NUM_CLICKS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | item3, item2, item1 | 20, 10, 5 |
| user2 | item1, item2, item3 | 10, 1, 1 |
| user3 | item2 | 1 |
| user4 | item1, item2 | 0, 2 |

Is this possible using SQL (esp. for Snowflake syntax)? TIA

I tried

```sql
SELECT user_id, using ARRAY_UNIQUE_AGG(item_id) AS clicked_items
FROM clickstream_table
GROUP_BY user_id
```

and got unique user_ids and corresponding list of items but not sure how to find number of times each item is clicked. I can do this easily using pandas but unfortunately I cannot even pull 1 month of data due to size and timeout limitations (3hr limit) on warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to aggregate your data to be like the following:

```
with data (user_id, item_name, click_count) as (
    select * from values
        ('user1', 'item1', 5),
        ('user1', 'item2', 10),
        ('user1', 'item3', 20),
        
        ('user2', 'item1', 10),
        ('user2', 'item2', 1),
        ('user2', 'item3', 1),

        ('user3', 'item2', 1),
        
        ('user4', 'item2', 10),
        ('user4', 'item2', 2)
)
```

the results you are after can be done with [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg) and [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct)

```
select 
     user_id, 
     array_agg(object_construct(item_name, click_count)) within group (order by click_count desc) as clicked_items   
from data
group by 1
order by 1;
```

gives:

| USER_ID | CLICKED_ITEMS |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | [ { "item3": 20 }, { "item2": 10 }, { "item1": 5 } ] |
| user2 | [ { "item1": 10 }, { "item2": 1 }, { "item3": 1 } ] |
| user3 | [ { "item2": 1 } ] |
| user4 | [ { "item2": 10 }, { "item2": 2 } ] |

or if you want it to look "exactly" like you have shown, then the second option can be done with two [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg)

```
select 
     user_id, 
     listagg(item_name, ', ') within group (order by click_count desc) as clicked_items,
     listagg(click_count, ', ') within group (order by click_count desc) as num_clicks 
from data
group by 1
order by 1;
```

giving:

| USER_ID | CLICKED_ITEMS | NUM_CLICKS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | item3, item2, item1 | 20, 10, 5 |
| user2 | item1, item2, item3 | 10, 1, 1 |
| user3 | item2 | 1 |
| user4 | item2, item2 | 10, 2 |

well, the first output can be created with string concatenations also.

```
select 
     user_id, 
     listagg(item_name||': '||click_count, ', ') within group (order by click_count desc) as clicked_items   
from data
group by 1
order by 1;
```

gives:

| USER_ID | CLICKED_ITEMS |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | item3: 20, item2: 10, item1: 5 |
| user2 | item1: 10, item2: 1, item3: 1 |
| user3 | item2: 1 |
| user4 | item2: 10, item2: 2 |

Comment: This really helpful. Thank you very much Simeon! 

Only thing different is that I don't have the click counts. Basically, the number of times an item_id occurs in the table (for a fixed user_id) gives the click_count by that user.

Comment: This as you note. You know how to goup by the user id and do a count.  Thus why i opened with assuming you know how to get the aggregate counts.